# Usable World Ray from 2D Mouse Coordinates?

Tags: c++, c, glm-math, raycasting

I'd like to construct a world ray given a mouse click, which can be used to run intersection checks.

The ray should be generated, given `glm::vec2` mouse coordinate and `glm::mat4` projection and view matrix's. Taking into account near and far planes. How can this be implemented in C?

Edit:
I have constructed a mouse ray from `mousePosition`, `view` and `projection`. the coordinates it returns are close to what I'm after however `mouseRay.z` isn't behaving at all.

```
glm::vec2 mousePosition = { .x, .y };
glm::vec2 normalisedCoords = {
 -1.0f + 2.0f * position.x / width,
  1.0f + -2.0f * position.y / height
};
glm::vec4 clipCoords = { normalisedCoords.x, normalisedCoords.y, -1, 1 };
glm::mat4 invertedProjection = glm::inverse(projection);
glm::vec4 eyeCoords = invertedProjection * clipCoords;
glm::mat4 invertedView = glm::inverse(view);
glm::vec4 rayWorld = invertedView * eyeCoords;
glm::vec3 mouseRay = { rayWorld.x, rayWorld.y, rayWorld.z };
printf("x: %f, y: %f, z: %f\n\r", rayWorld.x, rayWorld.y, rayWorld.z);
```

Comment: I should have added, you will need to *project* the homogeneous `rayWorld` coordinate, which may not have `(w == 1.0f)` - so you need to divide all components of `rayWorld` by `rayWorld.w`. Unless you want your ray to be expressed in homogeneous coordinates - which you typically don't.

Answer (score 1):

Given a projection matrix: **[P]**, and view matrix: **[V]**, the transformation: **`[M] = [P][V]`** is applied to yield geometry in a homogeneous clip coordinate space (CCS). After projection, you have a point in normalized device coordate space (NDCS). That point is then mapped to your viewport, and a depth buffer - which is why it's sometimes referred to as a '3d viewport'.

Given the 2D mouse coordinates: `(x, y)`, you need a linear transform to map `(x, y)` back to normalized coordinates: `(x_ndc, y_ndc)` using the viewport: `{vx, vy, vw, vh}` parameters. You can lookup how OpenGL maps to the '3D viewport', and apply the inverse of this transform to `(x)` and `(y)` coordinates.

This yields a (homogeneous) point on the picking ray: `(x_ndc, y_ndc, -1, +1)` ... it's a point on the `W = - Z` plane, which is what the 'near' plane was mapped to - don't get too bothered by notions of clipping (hyper) planes at this point!

Assuming the `eye` point: `(ex, ey, ez, 1)`, is in world coordinate space (WCS), we want to find: **`inv([M]) = inv([V]) * inv([P])`** to apply to: `(x_ndc, y_ndc, -1, +1)`.

So the mouse point `(x, y)` represents: `r1 = inv([M]) * (x_ndc, y_ndc, -1, +1)` in world coordinate space. The origin of the ray is the `eye` point: `r0 = (ex, ey, ez, +1)`. Finally, the ray direction: `rt = r1 - r0 * r1.w` ensures: `rt.w = 0` - a *vector*, not a point.

You now have a ray in *world* coordinate space: `r(t) = r0 + t.rt, t > 0`

---

This does require a good understanding of matrix properties, homogeneous coordinates, etc. But you should be able to find some other GLM examples that construct a picking ray originating at the *eye* using these principles. You can always dig more deeply into the theory later, and satisfy yourself as to *why* this works.

Comment: Can you update your answer with some working code?

Comment: Following on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71731722/correct-way-to-generate-3d-world-ray-from-2d-mouse-coordinates

Answer (score 0):

Your view frustum has near and far planes(the far one is where the visibility gets cut off). A mouse click is two points:

1. one plane representing viewer's eye.
2. one in the far view frustum representing the flat horizon. The flat horizon is scaled 2d plane from the viewer's eye.

Therefore you can construct a 3d line segment by connecting the near and far segments. In notation it be
(nearx,neary,nearz) and (farx,fary,farz)
However using the observation about 2. you can say how you set up the frustrum that

> farx = nearx - xscale fary = neary - yscale farz = nearz - zscale.

Note all scale variables are constants

Depending on your coordinate system and projection x and y could mean different things in your setup. It's best to just take your frustrum and measure out those values to know what goes where.

Ok from this you can plug in:
(nearx,neary,nearz), (nearx-xscale,neary-yscale,nearz - zscale)

That's two coordinates but a ray is simple a vector which signifies magnitude and direction(and the line coming from one segment to the other). So todo that just apply subtraction
[nearx - (nearx -xscale), neary - (neary-yscale), nearz -(nearz - zscale)]

Technically the ray can be two ways depending on which way you build it up either from the eye to the far away or faraway to the eye.

To run intersections you'll have to convert the ray from view space to world space.

You can google ray picking for your favorite api. The implementation will depend on the api you choose. But this is the linear algebra in a nutshell.

One more note. Depending on your use case it may not be desirable to have a ray mouse click. It's possible you want the planes perpendicular. For certain tile based problems this could be desirable. This can be done easy by setting them the same 2d sizes for certain axis.

Comment: Can you update your answer with some working code?

Comment: 1. apply glm::vec2 mouse coordinate to your camera vector and call this the far vector. This will give you the intersection of your mouse from the eye.  assuming the 2d vector is offset from the middle of the screen.
2. Get 2nd point by adding the faroff to your new vector the near vector. Just use your camera class rotation and orientation to figure out your orientation. 3. Follow the typical camera translation for both points and you have a ray in world matrix form.  4. write a unit test with the far off plane and validate it numerical. This will give you certainty it's right.

Comment: I added some of my code.. can you help validate

Comment: Following on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71731722/correct-way-to-generate-3d-world-ray-from-2d-mouse-coordinates